# Unable to get the current count from sqlite database in android using Group By clause

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I have a table in `SQLite` database as follows:

`JobId STRING,RigId STRING,area STRING,spares STRING,spare_id STRING`

I want to get the count of the number of rows that have the same spare_id i.e if 4 rows have spare_id=2, then the count returned should be 4.

I have written the following query but I am not getting the proper count. Can anyone tell me why. My code is as follows:

```
public int get_report_entry_spare_count(String jobId,
        String RigID) {

    String countQuery="SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS spare_id FROM spare_replaced GROUP BY spare_id ";

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int total = c.getInt(0);
    // int total = c.getCount();
    c.close();
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `c.getInt(0)` try `c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("spare_id"));`

Comment: the count always returns as 1

Comment: Try `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(c)` to debug the cursor data. For `COUNT(*) AS spare_id` use `spare_id_count` or something instead of  `spare_id` as you already have column with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code.

```
 public int get_report_entry_spare_count(String jobId,
            String RigID) {

        String countQuery="SELECT  COUNT(*) AS spare_id FROM spare_replaced GROUP BY spare_id ";

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int total = c.getInt(0);        
        c.close();
        return total;
    }
```